# tinyows fid returned as table_name.null?

Tags: gis, openlayers, postgis, pgadmin

i am trying to use tinyows for wfs-t in my app along with openlayers and postgis.
i am using osm tables and myown tables for storing geom.
tinyows working fine with osm tales, but returning table_name.(null) as **fid** for requested features.
so i am unable to do wfs-t on my tables.
How to solve this error, where is my mistake ? any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be problem with postgre updation i think.
If i create a table by command line/or by sql window instead of using pgadmin3 graphical interface, I am getting a working table.
But if i create a table with GUI in Pgadmin3 there is s problem.

any how i am having my own table working wfs-t through tinyows.

Thanks Friends.